# Learning Intel's TBB

Tags: c++, multithreading, intel, tbb

Could anyone recommend good book about [Intel's threading library](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) and how to use it?

Comment: About your P.S.: It's in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). As far as I know, the exact criteria are secret. I also like to refer people to [this](http://sscce.org) (also this does not pertain to your current question).

Comment: There’s also [another FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). I think in your case the question was simply so short that the heuristic of the site was triggered. The question looks OK to me.

Comment: @Kondrad it's rather poor design to tell to user that error occured but without giving a reason, just so vague "our quality bladi blah"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The O'Reilly book indeed does have poor reviews. I haven't come across any other books, but what will really help you with learning TBB is:
To go through the [reference manual](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/uploads/81/91/Latest%20Open%20Source%20Documentation/Reference.pdf) one concept at a time and make tiny code samples of your own. The TBB samples are HUGE, and weren't very helpful when I tried learning it. I made small pieces of code and tried out the concepts. That's the best way to explore and learn TBB (until a good book comes out).
Happy learning! :)

Comment: thanks, will look it up later on.

Answer (score 4):

I found the [O'Reilly book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514808) useful. The library is complex, but the book gives a good introduction to it.

Comment: judging by reviewers' comments it is rather poorly written book, with lots of faults. What's your opinion on that?

Comment: I don't think it's the best written book in the world, but I was able to understand what the library was trying to provide and at least the basics of how it provided it. From there I'd probably head straight over to the API docs.